# How can a proxy be set for the whole xubuntu system?

Tags: proxy, xubuntu

Hello I need to find out how to enable a system wide proxy in xubuntu 10.10

Comment: I am not sure that this question is clear. What is the proxy suppose to do? - Please add some more information that realistic answers can be given.

Comment: I think it is reasonably clear the user is looking for an Xubuntu alternative to Ubuntu/Gnome's System->Preferences->Network Proxy

Answer (score 7):

Whilst the the other answers are good & ok (for terminal/bash prompts), in my opinion the correct place to add these are `/etc/environment`.

Use `sudo` or `gksu` then add:

```
http_proxy="http://user:password@proxyserver:port"
https_proxy="http://user:password@proxyserver:port"
ftp_proxy="http://user:password@proxyserver:port"
```

Very similar but for those who run everything from within a term then yes the other answers will give results but for those in GUI land would be better off adding the above line to the environment file for full correct system wide usage.

Comment: You must also want to mention the capital lettered version of the above.

Answer (score 6):

Add to following lines to your ~/.bashrc file:

```
export http_proxy="http://user:password@proxyserver:port"
export https_proxy="http://user:password@proxyserver:port"
export ftp_proxy="http://user:password@proxyserver:port"
```

Comment: This will set a proxy for the user, not the system.

Comment: Wouldn't you simply add them to /etc/bash.bashrc then to make it system wide?

Answer (score 1):

there is a graphical tool called UbProxy, that sets the whole systema proxy, via a graphical interface (GUI).
The only problem for me, was I have to log out my user and log in again to load the config.
Is very simple to use.
https://code.google.com/p/ubproxy/