# How do I set a global SOCKS proxy in Xubuntu?

Tags: configuration, xubuntu, proxy, xfce

I saw a similar thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6943/how-can-a-proxy-be-set-for-the-whole-xubuntu-system), but this doesn't specify how to specify a SOCKS proxy globally.

In vanilla Ubuntu there was a proxy configuration program that affected the entire system.  Is there something similar in Xubuntu?  If not, is there a way to manually configure this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to set a global SOCKS proxy, many applications do not have SOCKS proxy support.
What you can do is use utility like "tsocks" which tunel all the TCP connections from an application using the SOCKs server.

tsocks is available from the repositories.

Comment: Tried out tsocks and was having trouble getting it to work.  I'll have to try again later when I have more time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a global socks proxy but I do make frequent use of foxyproxy for firefox and ssh port forwarding.

Comment: Firefox has the ability to configure a SOCKS proxy built in.