# How can gnome based applications such as rhythmbox use a proxy

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, proxy

I happen to be using xubuntu but I dont think the desktop-environment is applicable in this context.

I noticed that some gnome-based applications such as rhythmbox cannot fetch any information from the internet if the corporate network is using a proxy.

In this particular scenario - the cover-art search facility of rhythmbox cannot find coverart sought from the various providers on the internet.

I've tried the usual tricks such as setting *http_proxy* and running rhythmbox from the terminal, but this does not seem to work.

- [How can a proxy be set for the whole xubuntu system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6943/how-can-a-proxy-be-set-for-the-whole-xubuntu-system)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some of the newer GTK3 based gnome-applications ignore/don't use environment variables when dealing with proxies.

Instead, they use values stored in *gsettings* / *dconf*

If you use `dconf-editor` installed as part of the `dconf-tools` package you can define the proxy in a GUI manner.

First - set the proxy mode to *manual* as shown

[image]

Second - set the proxy host & port.  If you dont have an anonymous proxy you need to set the authentication-password and authentication-user values

[image]

If your corporate network uses `https` then set the equivalent *system - proxy - https* tree values instead of *system - proxy - http* that is shown above.

Via the terminal you can use the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual' 
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host 'proxy.askubuntu.com'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port 8080
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-user '[host]\[username]'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-password 'mypassword'
```

Where `[host]\[username]` corresponds to your corporate network credentials e.g. `mywindowsdomain\fossfreedom`

If your corporate network uses `https` then substitute `http` with `https` in the above terminal commands.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks, I'll add this to the [general non-Unity proxy settings answer!](http://askubuntu.com/a/151047/58612)