# How to configure proxy for online account authentication

Tags: proxy, online-accounts

When I try to register a new online account the authentication screen just hangs and finally ends in "An error occured while loading the authenication page".

I have tried to do this both at work (where it hangs) and at home, where it works perfectly. The difference is that at work we have a proxy.

[image: authentication loading]

I have tried to configure the proxy in the system and "apply system wide" but the authentication still hangs on 'loading' animation.

[image: proxy configuration]

So the question is, how do I configure a proxy for the authentication in online accounts dialog?

Comment: In my case, these lines are already set. But I have the same error.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this problem is to use dconf-editor, as reported here: [How can gnome based applications such as rhythmbox use a proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186561/how-can-gnome-based-applications-such-as-rhythmbox-use-a-proxy)

Thanks to [Jobin](https://askubuntu.com/users/72576/jobin) for his link to the above solution, see his post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230590/prox-authentication-issue-with-online-accounts-12-10)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflowstackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.