# Prox* authentication issue with online accounts (12.10)

Tags: 12.10, proxy, facebook, online-accounts

I want to use Ubuntu's online accounts feature to access my Facebook account. The thing is, my school has a proxy server you have to use to access https sites. So I configured my proxy settings accordingly. I am pretty sure the proxy setting is right because I logged into Facebook with Chrome. But when I try to log in with Ubuntu "online accounts" feature, it gives me this error.[image]

I am not totally sure it is a proxy problem either. I copy pasted the url into chrome and it works.

PS: The title is weird because my ISP blocks any url with the word proxy in it, and the title is incorporated into the url.

Please help!!

Comment: Possible bug? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/signon/+bug/1095254

Comment: @fossfreedom Agree, looks like this bug. Good find!

Answer (score 1):

## Manually Edit the Configuration File

Open the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf` by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and running `gksu gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf`. Don't worry if it is an empty file. Add these lines into the file and save it:

```
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://Username:Your_password@domain:port-no/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://Username:Your_password@domain:port-no/";
Acquire::http::proxy "http://Username:Your_password@domain:port-no/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://Username:Your_password@domain:port-no/";
```

Replace `username` by the username assigned to you and the `password` by your password, `domain` by the domain of your proxy like `10.1.101.150`, which is my college's proxy address and by the `port no` like `3128` or the one which you have, if you do have these parameters assigned to you, else leave out username and password and also the characters: `:` and `@` upto `domain`.

To add proxy authentication parameters to other applications, have a look at this [answer to a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186561/how-can-gnome-based-applications-such-as-rhythmbox-use-a-proxy/186562#186562).

## Use the Easy GUI Utility

Another way to add this information is by going to **System Settings → Network → Network Proxy** then add your proxy settings and click on **Apply Settings System-wide**. This will add the proxy settings but you will have to add the user-name and password manually using the command-line method described above.

Comment: What do the APT-proxy settings have to do with this? The OP is setting up "Online accounts".

Comment: Oh yes, I was not aware that "online accounts" need to set a proxy in some different file. I won't be able to say which file needs to be edited. Sorry for being silly.

Comment: Ok, so I figured out that some of the applications can be configured to use proxy authentication by setting the configuration in the dconf-editor. [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/186561/how-can-gnome-based-applications-such-as-rhythmbox-use-a-proxy) question may help the user to set proxy and solve the problem.

Comment: Can you include this in your answer, rather than posting it as a comment?

Comment: Added link to the answer I referred to. Re-posting it here would have hardly helped, as it is well explained and formatted.