# Online Accounts, Email, and Spotify can't connect or authenticate (12.10)

Tags: thunderbird, proxy, online-accounts, spotify

I have set my proxy settings and applied them system wide. I can access the internet and get my email etc. though firefox (and Chrome), but whenever I try an app that needs to access the internet, it says I need to check my password.

I tried the fix listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230590/prox-authentication-issue-with-online-accounts-12-10) as well as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186561/how-can-gnome-based-applications-such-as-rhythmbox-use-a-proxy/186562#186562) to make sure my proxy settings are being recognized by all the applications, but neither of them made a difference. There was also talk of this being a possible [bug as listed here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/signon/+bug/1095254) but it is listed as "fix released."

Edit: More info- Whenever I try to run one of these programs I end up getting this error message (this is specifically the one from everpad):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/everpad/provider/sync.py", line 361, in run
self.init_network()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/everpad/provider/sync.py", line 377, in init_network self.note_store = get_note_store(self.auth_token)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/everpad/provider/tools.py", line 51, in get_note_store http_proxy=get_proxy_config(urlparse(user_store_uri).scheme))
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/thrift/transport/THttpClient.py", line 72, in init
raise ValueError("Unsupported Proxy Scheme, %s" % http_proxy.scheme)
ValueError: Unsupported Proxy Scheme, https
```

Does anyone know what I can do? or let me know if I need to run some tests etc. to get you some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe is was a bug in 12.10 when dealing with proxy servers... I upgraded to 13.04 and didn't have a problem.

Also, there was still the problem with thunderbird after upgrading, but switching the settings within thunderbird to use "no proxy" it worked out fine.